# Error receiving while loading the pickle in ANN model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am new in deep learning and apologies if the question was asked earlier as i am not able to find relevant content so asking.

Need one help regarding error which i am getting while building a model in neural network(ANN).

I am trying to build ANN model on TensorFlow using features column.

However I am able to execute EDA steps and build the model and can generate the pickle as well.

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
model = Sequential()
model.add(feature_layer)
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_ds,epochs=10)
```

```
model.save('ann_model')
```

While loading the pickle for testing it shows the error:

```
model = load_model('ann_model')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 1
----> 1 model = load_model('ann_model')

File ~/isolation/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/isolation/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/serialization.py:272, in _deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    270   obj = custom_objects.get(object_name)
    271 else:
--> 272   obj = module_objects.get(object_name)
    273   if obj is None:
    274     raise ValueError(
    275         'Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + object_name)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Note: I have tried with different approach but same error.

Can anyone suggest me on this ?

I have tried with different options like pickle, h5 and save model but unfortunately receive the same error.

So I am expecting from some one to understand the problem and provide me the steps or idea to rectify this error which will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the compile argument to False when loading the model. This will prevent the model from trying to recompile itself during the loading process, which can sometimes cause issues with deserialization. For example:

```
model = load_model('ann_model', compile=False)
```